# is the OutlineButton still exist? or only the OutlinedButton exist

Tags: flutter

availability of OutlinedButton.

The availability  status of OutlineButton in flutter is   not clear.Is that still available? Are there any updates or what? When I tried this code it doesn't work

```
**OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Icon(Icons.remove),
  ),**
```

Answer (score 0):

It does exist, indeed, but something that has changed is how flutter manages styling of these buttons. You can handle them in a Theme class, for example, but the reason why the code you provided doesn't work is that the parameter **style** of the bottom doesn´t expect a **RoundedRectangleBorder** type, but a **MaterialStateProperty**.

To make the code work, you should do something like this:

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ButtonStyle(
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0))
  ),
  child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
),
```